# Получение списка всех пользователей

Tags: c#, windows

Есть терминальный сервер нужно:
1. Программно получить список всех пользователей запущенных на компьютере (как в диспетчере задач Windows)
2. Получить из них список всех активных в данный момент
Может подскажите решение или куда копать, желательно на c# или powershell

Comment: копайте в сторону WMI, подробностей уже не помню, но что-то подобное делал, к сожалению скриптов не сохранилось. А вообще, может опишите более общую задачу? может есть решение проще, на базе доменных политик например.

Comment: Не шарп и не пошик, но тоже майкрософт: https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/psloggedon

Comment: @don утилита русиновича к сожалению не указывает отдельно активных пользователей, так что к сожалению не подходит

Comment: @rdorn задача географически распределенный терминальный сервер. На брокер к которому подключаются пользователи должна приходить статистика со всех терминалов о наличии активных и закрытых сессий.

Comment: Сталкивался с похожей задачей. Сделал виндовую службу, которая "мониторила" системный журнал (там можно поймать события начала и конца сеанса rdp с именами пользователей и ip). Если интересен такой способ решения, могу накидать куски кода.

Comment: @eblomyac давай.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени. Не имею возможность комментировать, однако вот интересная ссылка:
[C# Get RDC/RDP and “Console” Session information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987213/c-sharp-get-rdc-rdp-and-console-session-information)

Так же можно заюзать утилиту qwinsta